# Multidimension Array in PHP - add extra dimension?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($dates as $dbRow) :
$datesExp[] = [$counter => array($dbRow->e_id => new DateTime($dbRow->l_date_expect))];
++$counter;
endforeach;
```

Using the above code, I'm trying to achieve is an array in format of:

```
0 => array(
    PK => DATE)
1 => array(
    PK2 => DATE2)
....etc
```

But what i'm getting with a var_dump is:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          2 => 
            object(DateTime)[7]
```

Where is this:
`array (size=1)
0=>`
 intermediate dimension coming from?

Comment: Have you tried this at line 3 instead: `$datesExp[$counter] = array($dbRow->e_id => new DateTime($dbRow->l_date_expect));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: `$datesExp[] = [$counter => array($dbRow->e_id => new DateTime($dbRow->l_date_expect))];`

`$datesExp[] =` = add the following as an entry in this array

`[...];` = everything in here is an array

`array($dbRow->e_id => new DateTime($dbRow->l_date_expect))` = the innermost array

should be

`$datesExp[$counter] = array($dbRow->e_id => new DateTime($dbRow->l_date_expect));`

Comment: Thanks Francis this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this ,no need of seperate counter,no need of outside braces [..]

```
$datesExp[] = array($dbRow->e_id => new DateTime($dbRow->l_date_expect));
```